# Show facebook comments on site

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Is it possible to mirror Facebook comments from my Facebook page on a post to my site using the comments plugin?  I've been searching and cant really find anything regarding this subject. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to "mirror" that, then this is probably possible by using:

```
GET /{POST-ID}/comments?access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

However, if you are looking for a plugin, the nearest plugin for this is the [Embedded Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts#faq) but that will only show the numbers of comments:

> **What do people see in Embedded Posts?**
>   The embedded post will show any
>   media attached to it, as well as the number of likes, shares, and
>   comments that the post has. Embedding posts will let people using your
>   web site see the same rich information that is shown on Facebook.com,
>   and they will enable people to **follow or like content authors or Pages
>   directly from the embed.**